# How to send a JSON array to a server using the post method?

Tags: android, json

How to send a JSON array to a server using the post method?

```
{
 "user_id":"1",
 "username":"shubham",
 "order":[{"product_id":"2","qty":"5","price":"100","total":"500","product_name":"choclate"},{"product_id":"1","qty":"2","price":"50","total":"500","product_name":"choclate"}]
}
```

Comment: First this is not Json array, this is Json with an order element having an array. Did u look at jax Rs ?

Comment: Invalid JSON put array closing bracket `]` on `order` array

Comment: It is the format of data i have to send on sever

Comment: ok, you want to create this JSON and send it to the server?

Comment: Can you at least tell us what language you are using?

Comment: @ShaliniRathore which library you are using for server call?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `JSON` using below method and send it to server via whatever library you are using

```
private JSONObject getRequestJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject= new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("user_id", 1);
        jsonObject.put("username", "Shubham");
        //Order Array
        JSONArray orderJson=new JSONArray();
        //Order Object
        JSONObject orderObject=new JSONObject();
        orderObject.put("product_id",2);
        orderObject.put("qty",5);
        orderObject.put("price",100);
        orderObject.put("total",500);
        orderObject.put("product_name","choclate");
        // Add Order object to order array
        orderJson.put(orderObject);
        //Order Object
        JSONObject orderObject1=new JSONObject();
        orderObject1.put("product_id",3);
        orderObject1.put("qty",2);
        orderObject1.put("price",100);
        orderObject1.put("total",200);
        orderObject1.put("product_name","choclate");
        orderJson.put(orderObject1);
        //Add order array to main jsonObject
        jsonObject.put("order",orderJson);

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in your module level gradle file.

```
compile'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Create a class for your json model

```
public class OrderRequest{
   int user_id;
   String username;
   List<Order> order;
   public class Order{
        int product_id;
        int qty;
        float price;
        float total;
        String product_name;
   }
}
```

Create object of the above class in your activity and set all values.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String orderJson = gson.toJson(orderRequestObject);
```

Set orderJson as post parameter.